Taking an integral of a function whose derivative value at a point is given
Let $\phi: R\to R$ be a differentiable function. For some fixed point $x_1\in R$, it is given that
$$
\phi'(x_1) = a_1.
$$
Is it correct to integrate both sides from $x_1$ to $x$ and, by using the fundamental theorem of calculus, obtain
$$
\phi(x) - \phi(x_1) = a_1 (x-x_1)?
$$

You can't do that, once you evaluate $\phi'(x)$ at $x_1$ it becomes a constant so after integrating you get $\phi'(x_1)(x-x_1)=a_1(x-x_1)$. What you got is the approximation of $1^{\text{st}}$ order of the function $\phi(x)$ at $x_1$, but that's not how you argue into it.
